# Javascript on paste: check if pasted content comes from word

Tags: javascript, event-handling, copy-paste, paste, cpu-word

Is it possible to check where a pasted content comes from?
Because I need to check if a pasted content was copied from a word file...

So, is there something in javascript like:

```
  example.on('paste', function (event) {
     if (event.source == "Word") {
        // do something
     }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like this question falls into the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289905). It’d be quite a security and privacy concern if this was possible. What exactly do you need to do with this information? Copy the formatting in addition to the text? Paste as image? See [`DataTransfer`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) and [Clipboard API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

Comment: You can try `if (clipboardContent.indexOf('“') !=-1)`... (curly quote) if that is what bothers you

Comment: @SebastianSimon I need to remove all Office Codes. These are class-attributes starting with Mso...

Comment: It's not possible, maybe you could read the text from the clipboard and test for rich text  formatting.

Comment: @Vektor how do I check for rich text formatting?

Comment: @Michelle my bad, I just tried doing it to no avail. It's not possible I'm afraid.

Comment: @Vektor okay, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I need to remove all Office Codes. These are class-attributes starting with Mso*

Why not check for what you need to fix?

```
const text = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text')
if (text && text.toUpperCase().match(/"MSO/)) ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is the better option! Thanks for this idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, you need the clipboard API, and you only have access to executing the copy and paste commands. This will allow you to read or write content only.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

If you look at the clipboard API, you only get a read string or a DataTransfer instance. Which doesn't include any information on the source of the clipboard contents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You are right, I build my answers in edits.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible in **web** because if you copy any text from any source it will be same, And you are just copying that text, not source info,
So that's impossible